# Get sub array based on array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a `categories` array:

```
{id: 1, catName: "test", subCategories: Array(2)}
```

I need to retrieve the `subCategories` array based on the `id` of the `category`.

This return the entire `category` object, how can I change it to only return the `subCategories` array?

```
  const subCategories = categoriesWithSub.filter(category => {
    return category.id === departments.catId;
  });
```

Comment: _I have a categories array.._ That looks like object, not an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destructure a `find` call:

```
const { subCategories } = categoriesWithSub.find(({ id }) => id === departments.catId);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
let categories = [ {id: 1, catName: "test", subCategories: ["test1","test2"]}, {id: 2, catName: "test", subCategories: Array(2)} ]
let departments = { catId: 1 }
const subCategories = categories.find(category => {
    return category.id === departments.catId;
  }).subCategories;
console.log( subCategories );
```

Comment: ```filter``` will return an array, ```subCategories``` will therefor be undefined.

```[0].subCategories;```

Would do the trick, but you'd need to be sure that ```filter``` always yields results.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the object and get the array using [dot notation or bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```
const subCategories = (categoriesWithSub.find(category => {
  return category.id === departments.catId;
}) || {}).subCategories; // if find returns undefined then use an empty object to avoid error, alternately you can use if condition
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`.

```
const subCategories = categoriesWithSub.reduce((acc, category) => {
  if (category.id === departments.catId) {
    return acc.concat(category. subCategories)
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Side note, `reduce` is a really powerful tool. `find`, `map`, `forEach`, `filter` are like shorthand versions of `reduce` for specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getSubCategory() {
        var categoriesWithSub = [{ id: 1, catName: "test", subCategories: ["test1","test2"] }, { id: 2, catName: "test", subCategories: ["test1","test2"] }]
        var catId = 1;

        for (var category = 0; category < categoriesWithSub.length; category++) {
             if (categoriesWithSub[category].id == catId)
                return categoriesWithSub[category].subCategories;
        }
    }
```